# Is it possible to call another contract and not pay transaction cost(~20k gas)?

Tags: gas, contract-invocation

The thing is that I need to reach the maximum stack depth. When I try to recursively call myself I run out of gas, because each call requires  at least ~20k gas.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate to http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8216/reproducing-stack-depth-attack or otherwise more information is needed.  CALL opcodes only cost 40 gas; writing a new value to storage is 20,000 gas.